# Java Complex JSON parsing (variable fields)

Tags: java, json

I have an output in JSON which comes as below. I have tried parsing it with a lot of programs (Program also below) but it all fails, Primarily because I think that the name of the child of "highlighting" element is not fixed, it is a changable URL. The URLs get displayed in the same order in the "response" field above that section..Any advice would be highly appreciated.

JSON code --

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1386,
    "params":{
      "fl":"urlFull",
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"hello",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2016,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "urlFull":"http://www.hellodesign.com/"},
      {
        "urlFull":"http://kadlot.com/"},
      {
        "urlFull":"http://insanityprone.tumblr.com/"},
      {
        "urlFull":"http://www.privatevoyeur.com/PSOctober13/am23043/index.html"},
      {
        "urlFull":"http://www.privatevoyeur.com/PSOctober13/am23043/qvindex.html"},
      {
        "urlFull":"http://seoul-arts.123.st/f268-hello"},
      {
        "urlFull":"http://www.edugeek.net/groups/south-west-techs/178-hello/"},
      {
        "urlFull":"http://www.gatewaytoroleplay.com/t1271-hello"},
      {
        "urlFull":"http://www.4networking.biz/forum/ViewPost/1078797"},
      {
        "urlFull":"http://www.sysaid.com/Sysforums/posts/list/9104.page"}]
  },
  "highlighting":{
    "http://www.hellodesign.com/":{
      "title":["<b>Hello</b>"],
      "fulltxt":["<b>Hello</b> You need the Latest Flash Player to view this site. Click here to download Flash Click here if you know you have Flash Address 10305 Jefferson Blvd. Culver City, CA 90232 Telephone 310-839-4885",
        " Fax 310-839-4886 Email New Business newbusiness@hellodesign.com Press Inquiries press@hellodesign.com Career Inquiries careers@hellodesign.com General Inquiries <b>hello</b>@hellodesign.com"],
      "relatedLinks":["=&quot;mailto:hello@hellodesign.com&quot;  title=&quot;<b>hello</b>@hellodesign.com&quot;&gt;<b>hello</b>@hellodesign.com&lt;/a&gt;"]},
    "http://kadlot.com/":{
      "title":["<b>Hello</b>!"],
      "fulltxt":["<b>Hello</b>! <b>Hello</b>! Sooo... I didn't have much time to give you a prezi with nice graphics, but I thought you could help me out* with the drawings at least! So I made this site you can draw on! Try it and"]},
    "http://insanityprone.tumblr.com/":{
      "title":["<b>Hello</b>..."],
      "fulltxt":["<b>Hello</b>... <b>Hello</b>... ~ And welcome to my facilities. Yes, mine. Not Her's. Mine. If you're curious about anything, anything at all, feel free to ask me. I've been here for a while now; I've picked a few",
        " they came into view. Well didn&#8217;t they look familiar. Vaguely so. &#8220;<b>Hello</b>..&#8221; he offered a thin grin, just a sliver of those white teeth, hoping to eminate a false sense of friendliness. While he did like"],
      "relatedLinks":[" - &lt;a href=&quot;http://insanityprone.tumblr.com/&quot;  title=&quot;<b>Hello</b>...&quot;&gt;<b>Hello</b>...&lt;/a&gt; - &lt;a href=&quot;http://insanityprone.tumblr.com/ask&quot;  title=&quot;Yes?&quot;&gt;Yes?&lt;/a&gt; - &lt;a href=&quot;http://insanityprone.tumblr.com/submit"]},
    "http://www.privatevoyeur.com/PSOctober13/am23043/index.html":{
      "title":["<b>Hello</b>"],
      "fulltxt":["<b>Hello</b> EscapeTrail PrivateVoyeur InstantPost Archive CamFuze PrivateVoyeur Proudly Presents: &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; <b>Hello</b> &#160;Contributor Story None &#160;From &#160; ... &#160;Comments by &#160; John &#160;Legal Advisory The photos"]},
    "http://www.privatevoyeur.com/PSOctober13/am23043/qvindex.html":{
      "title":["<b>Hello</b>"],
      "fulltxt":["<b>Hello</b> EscapeTrail PrivateVoyeur InstantPost Archive CamFuze PrivateVoyeur Proudly Presents: &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; <b>Hello</b> &#160;Contributor Story None &#160;Legal Advisory The photos below are copyright protected. You"]},
    "http://seoul-arts.123.st/f268-hello":{
      "title":["<b>HELLO</b>!"],
      "fulltxt":["<b>HELLO</b>! &#160; &#10085;S-A-U&#160;::&#160; ANNYEONG!&#160;::&#160; <b>HELLO</b>! &#160;! &amp; !&#160; &#160;Atsakymai&#160; &#160;Autorius&#160; &#160;Per&#382;i&#363;r&#279;jo&#160; &#160;Paskutinis prane&#353;imas&#160; !: MEET&#160; [ Pereiti prie: 1, 2, ... , 5, 6] 83 KIM JAEJOONG 365 Today at 7:27 pm PARK BOM",
        ": Nieko Moderatorius: STARS Permissions in this forum: J&#363;s negalite ra&#353;yti nauj&#371; prane&#353;im&#371; &#303; &#353;&#303; forum&#261; J&#363;s negalite atsakin&#279;ti &#303; prane&#353;imus &#353;iame forume &#160;&#10085;S-A-U&#160;::&#160;ANNYEONG!&#160;::&#160;<b>HELLO</b>! Vartotojai",
        ", per&#382;i&#363;rintys &#353;&#303; forum&#261;: Nieko &#160;&#10085;S-A-U&#160;::&#160;ANNYEONG!&#160;::&#160;<b>HELLO</b>! Pereiti &#303;:&#160;Pasirinkite forum&#261;||--ANNYEONG!|&#160;&#160;&#160;|--<b>HELLO</b>!|&#160;&#160;&#160;|--TAISYKL&#278;S|&#160;&#160;&#160;|--INFORMACIN&#278; D&#278;&#381;UT&#278;|&#160;&#160;&#160;|--NAUJOKO MENIU!|&#160;&#160;&#160;|--&#352;vieslent&#279;|&#160;&#160;&#160;|--B&#363;kim"],
      "relatedLinks":[" - &lt;a href=&quot;http://seoul-arts.123.st/forum&quot;  title=&quot;&#10085;S-A-U&quot;&gt;&#10085;S-A-U&lt;/a&gt; - &lt;a href=&quot;http://seoul-arts.123.st/c1-annyeong&quot;  title=&quot;ANNYEONG!&quot;&gt;ANNYEONG!&lt;/a&gt; - &lt;a href=&quot;http://seoul-arts.123.st/f268-<b>hello</b>"]},
    "http://www.edugeek.net/groups/south-west-techs/178-hello/":{
      "title":["<b>Hello</b>"],
      "fulltxt":["<b>Hello</b> Full Theme Forum Today's Posts Search &#160; <b>Hello</b> jimmy_2k 19th June 2010 10:59 AM Though i'd say hi, i'm from a school in Bristol SW-ICT 18th November 2011 10:21 AM Same!! Started off in Plymouth"],
      "relatedLinks":[" - &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.edugeek.net/groups/south-west-techs/178-<b>hello</b>/?groupid=21?&amp;styleid=38&quot;  title=&quot;Full Theme&quot;&gt;Full Theme&lt;/a&gt; - &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.edugeek.net/forums/&quot;  title=&quot;Forum&quot;&gt;Forum&lt;/a"]},
    "http://www.gatewaytoroleplay.com/t1271-hello":{
      "title":["<b>Hello</b> !!"],
      "fulltxt":["<b>Hello</b> !! Gateway to Role-Play A friendly community with various genres and freedom in role-play! Member of the Month &amp; Year: MethosArchaic Hey! Listen! If GtR has 100,000 overall posts on the board",
        " by the end of this year, Leah7 will dye her hair to popular vote, HikariKuragari will dye her hair red, and Venom will dye his hair the color of popular vote on the forum! <b>Hello</b> !! Gateway to Role-Play",
        "&#160;::&#160;Earth Realm&#160;::&#160;Introductions Page 1 of 2&#160;&#8226;&#160;Share&#160;&#8226;&#160; Page 1 of 2 &#8226; 1, 2&#160;&#160; &#160;&#160; <b>Hello</b> !! &#160;by&#160;Ange Tuteur on Mon Nov 11, 2013 3:56 am <b>Hello</b> I'm Ange Tuteur! I'll be honest I've never ever ever role played! So"],
      "relatedLinks":[" - &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.gatewaytoroleplay.com/t1271-<b>hello</b>&quot;  title=&quot;<b>Hello</b> !!&quot;&gt;<b>Hello</b> !!&lt;/a&gt; - &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.gatewaytoroleplay.com/forum&quot;  title=&quot;Gateway to Role-Play&quot;&gt;Gateway to Role-Play&lt;/a&gt; - &lt;a"]},
    "http://www.4networking.biz/forum/ViewPost/1078797":{
      "title":["<b>Hello</b>"],
      "fulltxt":["<b>Hello</b>\n Remember Me | Password reminder | New Member? Login Member login Shiny new version of #4N Meeting Finder App out now for Apple and Android http://t.co/4KDSZdwZH5 Home What's 4Networking",
        " forum Today's posts Last 24 hours Search forum Articles Meet the 4N Team FREE networking Home &gt; Forum &gt; SAY <b>HELLO</b>! &gt; <b>Hello</b> <b>Hello</b> Matt Reeds Frost Group Limited 0 Member Since: 11th Nov 2013 Telephone",
        ": Today at 04:18 Quote <b>Hello</b>, I am also new is 4networking to find some new frined. View Profile Send Message Leave Testimonial Find Posts &#160; Kat Evans Server Start Ltd 0 Member Since: 11th Nov 2013"],
      "relatedLinks":["&gt; - &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.4networking.biz/forum/ViewForum/4&quot;  title=&quot;SAY <b>HELLO</b>!&quot;&gt;SAY <b>HELLO</b>!&lt;/a&gt; - &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.4networking.biz/Members/Details/102151&quot;  title=&quot;Matt Reeds&quot;&gt;Matt Reeds&lt;/a&gt; - &lt;a href"]},
    "http://www.sysaid.com/Sysforums/posts/list/9104.page":{
      "title":["<b>Hello</b>"],
      "fulltxt":["<b>Hello</b> &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; Home &#160;&#160; Forums &#160;&#160; Feature Requests &#160;&#160; Beta Issues &#160;&#160; SysAid Resources &#160;&#160; Documentation &#160;&#160; Support <b>Hello</b> Guest,&#160; Login &#160;&#160; &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; DOWNLOAD FREE EDITION &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; Recent Topics &#160;&#160; Hottest",
        " Topics &#160;&#160; Online Members &#160;&#160; Member Listing &#160;&#160; Advanced Search <b>Hello</b> &#160; Forum Index &#187; General IT Discussions &#160; Author Message 10/12/2012 15:28:32 &#160;&#160; &#160;Subject: <b>Hello</b> Sveta Bondarenko SysAider Joined: 06/12"],
      "relatedLinks":["=396CBD1CE052DE09A50AB73C38C2D542&quot;  title=&quot;<b>Hello</b>&quot;&gt;<b>Hello</b>&lt;/a&gt; - &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.sysaid.com/Sysforums/forums/list.page;jsessionid=396CBD1CE052DE09A50AB73C38C2D542&quot;  title=&quot;Forum Index&quot;&gt;Forum Index&lt;/a&gt; - &lt;a href=&quot;http"]}},
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[]}}
```

Java code ------

```
  JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject(json);
  JSONObject innerObject = outerObject.getJSONObject("responseHeader");
  JSONArray jsonArray = innerObject.getJSONArray("title");
  for (int i = 0, size = jsonArray.length(); i < size; i++)
  {
    JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    // "...and get thier component and thier value."
    String[] elementNames = JSONObject.getNames(objectInArray);
    System.out.printf("%d ELEMENTS IN CURRENT OBJECT:\n", elementNames.length);
    for (String elementName : elementNames)
    {
      String value = objectInArray.getString(elementName);
      System.out.printf("name=%s, value=%s\n", elementName, value);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

Comment: + 1 for the interesting URLs and their targets in your JSON

Comment: Are you in charge of the schema? if so, why not attach the highlightings to the URLs by creating a unified object?

Comment: Hi David, the o/p comes from solr, I am not sure about the unified object...can you throw some light on this please? so that i can try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject innerObject = outerObject.getJSONObject("highlighting");

for(Object key : innerObject.keySet()) {         
    JSONObject o =innerObject.getJSONObject(key.toString());
    String[] elementNames = JSONObject.getNames(o);
    System.out.printf("%s >> %d ELEMENT(S) IN CURRENT OBJECT:\n", key, elementNames.length);
    for (String elementName : elementNames) {
        System.out.println(elementName);
        String value = o.get(elementName).toString();
        System.out.printf("name=%s, value=%s\n", elementName, value);
    }
    System.out.println();    
}
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
http://www.hellodesign.com/ >> 3 ELEMENT(S) IN CURRENT OBJECT:
relatedLinks
name=relatedLinks, value=["="mailto:hello@hellodesign.com"  title="hello@hellodesign.com">hello@hellodesign.com</a>"]
title
name=title, value=["Hello"]
fulltxt
name=fulltxt, value=["Hello You need the Latest Flash Player to view this site. Click here to download Flash Click here if you know you have Flash Address 10305 Jefferson Blvd. Culver City, CA 90232 Telephone 310-839-4885"," Fax 310-839-4886 Email New Business newbusiness@hellodesign.com Press Inquiries press@hellodesign.com Career Inquiries careers@hellodesign.com General Inquiries hello@hellodesign.com"]

...
```

`highlighting` is not a child of `responseHeader`, so I get right from the read json. Later I use the `keySet()` method to get the urls inside `highlighting`.

Comment: Change Method name from keySet() to keys() in outer for loop

Comment: There is no method with keySet in JSONObject

Comment: @AjayThakur I use `org.json.JSONObject`. It can be found here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20131018

Comment: @Christudas Drop the following jar on your classpath: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20131018/json-20131018.jar

Comment: i downloaded the jar from the url you gave & it compiles now...however on execution, it gives below error ---
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1
":{"
 ^

Comment: @Christudas The exception is not related to json I think. Look at this: *java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException*. It seems you're using a regexp. This regex has a syntax error. Check it.

Comment: it says valid json, i think it is due to the recursive elements in the json, somehow the program cant handle that

Comment: you are perfectly right, i removed it but now i am stuck with - Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["highlighting"] not found.

I am using the same json posted above....would appreciate advice ..thanks much

Comment: @Christudas Check the json again... There is no reason why `highlighting` can't be found...

Answer (score 0):

`innerObject` which corresponds to `responseHeader` does not have a field called `title`. What happens on the line `innerObject.getJSONArray("title");`?

Comment: +1 Simply returns null and very next line NullPointerException occurs

Comment: I know whatever I wrote is not an answer to the question but I spotted a mistake and wanted to bring it to notice. However, since I don't have reputation, I had to express it as an 'answer'. Sorry :(